# Pandas assign value to cell based on values of other cells in row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
DF = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['a','b','b'], 
                   'COL2' : [0,np.nan,1],})

DF

    COL1    COL2
0    a        0      
1    b       NaN     
2    b        1
```

I want to be able to assign a new column `COL3` that has a value of `2` for every row where `COL1` is `b` and `COL2` is not null.

The desired result is as follows:

```
    COL1    COL2    COL3
0    a        0      0
1    b       NaN     0
2    b        1      2
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
DF['COL3'] = np.where((DF['COL1'].isin(['b'])) &(DF['COL2'].notnull()), 2, 0)
print DF 


  COL1  COL2  COL3
0    a     0     0
1    b   NaN     0
2    b     1     2
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved using the [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method on the DataFrame. You'll need to pass in a function to apply to each row and set the axis to `1` to set it to the correct mode (apply for each row, instead of for each column).

Here's a working example:

```
def row_handler(row):
    if row['COL1'] == 'b' and not np.isnan(row['COL2']):
        return 2
    return 0

DF['COL3'] = DF.apply(row_handler, axis=1)
```

Which returns this:

```
>> print DF
  COL1  COL2  COL3
0    a     0     0
1    b   NaN     0
2    b     1     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a function to return your value based on other columns.

```
def value_handle (row):
    if row['COL1'] == 'b' and not pd.isnull(row['COL2']) :
        return 2
    else:
        return 0
```

Then call the new function when introducing the new column.

```
DF['COL3'] = DF.apply (lambda row: value_handle (row),axis=1)
```