# Python - Having trouble assigning value into new col based on data from another cell

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have data that looks like;

```
ID    File
1     this_file_whatever.ext1
2     this_whatever.ext2
3     this_is_ok_pooh.ext3
```

I am trying to get the extension and put the key from a dict in a new col based on the extension in `File`.

```
    def create_filegroups(row):
    filegroup_dict = {
        'GroupA': 'ext1',
        'GroupB': 'ext2',
        'GroupC': 'ext3'
    }
    if '.' in row['Name']:
        test = row['Name'].split(".",1)[1]
    return test

DF = build_df()
DF['COL3'] = DF.apply(create_filegroups(row), axis=1)
print(DF)
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. The dict compare I can do when I get there, but I can't seem to apply a function to the cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need [**`pandas.Series.map`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) after extracting the file extension from the column `File`.

Try this:

```
df['COL3']= (
                df['File']
                    .str.extract(r'\w+\.(\w+)', expand=False)
                    .map({k:v for v,k in filegroup_dict.items()})
            )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

   ID                     File    COL3
0   1  this_file_whatever.ext1  GroupA
1   2       this_whatever.ext2  GroupB
2   3     this_is_ok_pooh.ext3  GroupC
```

Comment: I wasn't naming it right. I named it `row_handler` / followed this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835906/pandas-assign-value-to-cell-based-on-values-of-other-cells-in-row